# ¿Como enviar un email con Laravel sin asociar ningún archivo blade, pero si una variable que contiene el html?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un proceso donde el usuario va construyendo en varios pasos el email que desea enviar, a tal punto que finalmente llego a tener todo el email completo dentro de una variable ($mitemplate).
Ahora bien, Laravel usualmente pide un template.blade para asociar al envío y le renderiza los datos que le ingresamos via función, pero en este caso no existe ningún template blade, lo que quiero es enviar lo que se encuentra en la variable $mitemplate (ahi esta todo el html ya listo), que ya contiene todas las configuraciones que hizo el usuario. Basicamente seria algo asi, aunque me da error, ya que me pide si o si el archivo blade :

```
//el template que reeemplaza el blade
$mitemplate='<html>..todo el template, etc etc</html>';

//el envio:
Mail::send($mitemplate, ['contenido' => $contenido], function ($m) use 
($contenido,$retorno) {
    $m->from('email@algo.com', 'Algun email');
    $m->to(['destino@xxxx.com'])->subject('el asunto del email');       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea cualquier archivo `blade` y solo imprime la variable que contiene el `HTML`

`Mail::to('alguien@alguien.com')->send(new TuClaseMail($mitemplate));`

Y ya dentro de tu clase tendrías algo así:

```
class TuClaseMail extends Mailable
{
   public $mitemplate;

   public function __construct($mitemplate){
       $this->mitemplate = $mitemplate;
   }

   public function build(){
      return $this->view('ruta.a.tu.vista');
   }
}
```

En tu vista, en este caso "`vista.blade.php`"

```
{!! $mitemplate !!}
```

Y listo

Comment: tenes razon! es lógico, ya mismo lo pruebo.

Comment: @rendor9 Vale, compruébalo y nos cuentas si te funcionó

Comment: Bueno, no usé maileables pero entendí con lo que me indicabas el error en mi lógica, genere un archivo blade vacío y le inyecte la variable con todo el contenido del html, y claro, esta funcionado perfecto.Gracias

Comment: Mail::send('templatesemail.template_base', ['mitemplate' => $mitemplate], function ($m) use ($mitemplate,$retorno) {
  $m->from('email@algo.com', 'Algun email');
    $m->to(['destino@xxxx.com'])->subject('el asunto del email');     
});